# How to substitute ::: in scala

Tags: list, scala

I have written a flatten function from scratch that takes a nested list as input and outputs another.

```
def flatten[A] (list:List[List[A]]):List[A]
```

I used scala's ':::' to bind the two lists and it worked fine. However, my exercise prohibits me from using that or any built in method ( exercise from a personal scala book).

Now, i have written a helper method that merges those two list called merge.

How would merge fit in a new version of the function flatten?

Answer (score 0):

If you have method merge you could use *foldLeft* for flattening the list of lists:

```
list.foldLeft(List[A]())(merge)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  def merge1[T](l1: List[T], l2: List[T]): List[T] = 
       l1.reverse.foldLeft(l2)((acc, e) => e :: acc)

  /** for large lists will throws Stackoverflow */
  def merge2[T](l1: List[T], l2: List[T]): List[T] = 
       l1.foldRight(l2)((e, acc) => e :: acc)


  def flatten[A](list: List[List[A]]): List[A] = 
       list.foldLeft(Nil: List[A])(merge1)
```

If you want to add your `merge` method to `List` type, you can write:

```
  implicit class ListExt[T](l: List[T]) {
    def merge(l2: List[T]): List[T] = merge1(l, l2)
  }


  def flatten2[A](list: List[List[A]]): List[A] = 
    list.foldLeft(Nil: List[A])((acc, e) => acc merge e)
```